# Show image per row depending on some value in the row in excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have an excel sheet with rows of data. For every row I want to display an image depending on some condition in this row.

Numerous tutorials can be found on how to show one Image based on some condition by creating a name, and adding some INDEX function with a SEARCH function. But in this function a relative offset of some kind seems not to work (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507253/excel-formula-to-reference-cell-to-the-left).

Is it possible to create a image lookup depending on some condition in the row for a number of rows without defining a name for each rows image?

Comment: "on how to show one Image based on some condition by creating a name..." where did you find them? What have you exactly tried? Why that didn't work?

Comment: an example http://exceltemplate.net/tutorial/how-to-display-images-dynamically-based-on-specific-cell-contents/ .If i create a name for each image, I need to specify the cell of which the name(and therefore image) depends on, it seems this value can't be relative. This would mean that I would need to create a manual name for each row.

Comment: could you please explain your downvote?

Answer (score 1):

I have come to the conclusion that this is not a supported use case. The only way to use dynamic images on a range of rows is by writing some vb plugin.